# "Over the last x years" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

Consider the sentence:

> His business acquired several computers over the last two years.

What is the best way to translate the phrase "**over the last two years**" in the above sentence? My best attempt would be **el los últimos dos años**, but I am certain there's a better translation a native speaker would use.

Comment: the most natural way is `en los últimos dos años` ó `en los dos últimos años`

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for

> durante los últimos X años
>   a lo largo de los últimos X años
>   en los últimos X años

Your example would be:

> Su negocio adquirió varios ordenadores durante los últimos dos años.

Comment: "Ordenador" is only used on the Eastern side of the Atlantic.

Comment: Where it is left over from when the only "computers" were IBM card sorters, hence "ordenador" or "sorter".

Comment: *Ordenador*, *Computador* and *Computadora* are correct. Here in Chile, we say *computador*.

Answer (score 2):

> Durante los dos años pasados

which really translates to

> During the past two years.

but I believe that it's the closest you're going to get.

Comment: *Desde los dos años pasados* doesn't make sense at all. *Durante los dos años pasados* sounds better. ;)

Comment: @EvaThyssen: What would you prefer in your regular conversation, "durante los dos años pasados" or "en los dos años pasados"?

Comment: @Amit, *durante* all the way! ;)